# Spring JDBC NamedParamJdbcTemplate transaction rollback when exception occurs?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions

I have two methods from my service class to dao class as shown below.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
     public void insertData() throws CCCServiceException {

    try {

            costCenterDaoImpl.addDatoToSales();
            costCenterDaoImpl.addDatoToProducts();
        }
```

If I got exception in addDatoToProducts() method , I need to rollback total transaction. But as of now i'm not able to rollback the transaction.

Please any one provide me the solution. Thanks in Advance.

Do I need to set auto commit false before transaction and set to true after transaction along with @transactional?

Comment: Before you go this method, try @Rollback(true)

Comment: Thanks, but where do I put this @Rollback either is service class or in dao class?

Comment: Still transaction for first method is committed. I'm getting DEBUG  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager]  Initiating transaction rollback only. But did not get any info like transaction is rolledback or not.

Comment: I have done this by implementing following.DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
  TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
  String object = transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<String>() {

   @Override
   public String doInTransaction(TransactionStatus ts) {
    try {                       costCenterDaoImpl.addDatoToSales();
            costCenterDaoImpl.addDatoToProducts();
} catch (Exception e) {
     
   ts.setRollbackOnly();
    }

Comment: Here I have not used any @transactional annotation.